# Categorising the different types of DC motors; Opinion needed

Tags: motor, dc-motor

I'm trying to build an understanding of the different DC motors and their properties.
When searching for "Types of DC motors" you'll often find this image:

[image]

This diagram is great, but I fail to see how the following motors fit in this picture:

- Brushed DC motor
- Brushless DC motor
- Stepper motor

Also, to add to my confusion, the following image seems to imply that BLDC motors are a type of AC motor.
I'm not sure what to think about that.

[image]

.
I know taxonomy is often debatable, but having experts' opinions would help me greatly.

You have my thanks.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on classification. All the first diagram are usually Brushed. It's a pretty old diagram. Most steppers are either PM or Variable Reluctance; as for the rest of the diagram, it's theoretically possible to make e.g. a field wound stepper but why would you want to? And yes, you need to generate AC (usually 3 phase) to drive a BLDC motor.

Comment: Hum fair enough for not getting too hung up on classification. As I'm learning, I felt it could be useful to get familiar with the mechatronics jargon.
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: The jargon is somewhat debatable. To me, "self excited" refers only to generators and perhaps induction motors. I would use the term "DC brushless" only for motors with all of the electronics built into the machine "integrated machines." There are a couple of types of motors missing from the second tree, wound rotor induction machines and synchronous reluctance with induction starting. The universal motors and the various types of single-phase motors are not covered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I agree with people saying that motors categorization should not be a priority, I still think it can be useful to organize information in conceptual diagrams for learning purposes.

Thus, allow me to share this diagram from *Sang-Hoon Kim - Electric Motor Control*.
I hope it can be useful to other people as well.

[image]